# Trying to take a backup of a database, but drives are different than in file explorer

Tags: ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio for SQL Server 2008, I do the following:

1. In the Object Explorer windows, right click on the database
2. Choose Tasks -> Back Up...
3. The Back Up Database windows appears. I choose 'Disk' under Destination
4. I choose 'Add...' under destination
5. The Select Backup Destination window appears. I choose '...'
6. The Locate Database Files window appears.

Now I want to save it to a network drive, but there are only three drives to choose from (C,G,H). But in any other place in windows there are C, and the network drives K, Q and Z. Why can't I save it on a network drive? And what is drive G and H? I'm fine with saving it on G or H, but where is it and how much space is left on these drives?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SMSS on the actual SQL server?

Or are you using SMSS on a local machine then connecting to SQL server over the network?

If you are connecting to a remote SQL Server over the network that would explain the differences in the drives you're seeing.